# Start project in CodePlex

Tags: codeplex

How can I start a project in CodePlex.com?

Answer (score 7):

Try going to CodePlex and [reading how to do this](http://www.codeplex.com/CodePlex/Wiki/View.aspx?title=CodePlex%20FAQ&referringTitle=Home) there.   [Register](https://www.codeplex.com/site/register)

Answer (score 2):

On the main page, there is a link on the left: [Create new project](http://www.codeplex.com/Project/ProjectCreation.aspx)

You will have to have a CodePlex account to do so.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.codeplex.com/Project/ProjectCreation.aspx

Just keep in mind that you have to release something (even if just partial source) within 30 days, or they delete your project.  It's not intended for private or closed source projects.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Create New Project](http://www.codeplex.com/Project/ProjectCreation.aspx) link on the left side of the page.

You will likely have to [register](https://www.codeplex.com/site/register) first.

Did you have a more specific question about the process?